# Extra sum of squares test in SAS proc glm

Tags: sas, linear-regression, glm

Given a regression model:

Y = b0 + b1*R + b2*S + b3*T

I'd like to test if S and T are jointly predictive. In SAS `proc reg`, it's quite easy to do:

```
proc reg;
model y = r s t;
test s, t;
run;
```

Does anyone know if the same test can be achieved in `proc glm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PROC GLM, you can use CONTRAST statement as explained in this example http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/compreg3.htm